# Php Variable doesnt reach included in included file

Tags: php

I have an issue. I have got a template file (`template_body.php`) being included in an `index.php` (`include_once("include/template_body.php");`)
in `template_body.php` i have got another file included called `header.php` (`include("header.php")`)

```
index.php -> template_body.php --> header.php
```

Now, in `index.php` i have got a boolean login check. But i can only access the boolean value in `template_body.php` and not in `header.php` .

Any way to achieve that?

Comment: check if your include of the `header.php` isn't before the variable ;)

Comment: i think header.php include the top of index.php page, but you create that varible in after include . so that variable is not geting in header.php file

Comment: I think you are following reverse chain..

Comment: The variable is definately set before including template_body.php

Comment: Are you sure it's not set inside a function or you're trying to use the variable inside a function?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look on this post answer about variable scope in php:

[Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

The below example is working

**index.php**

```
<?php
  $test = "test";
  include_once("file1.php");
?>
```

**template_body.php**

```
<?php
  include("header.php");
?>
```

**header.php**

```
<?php
  echo $test;
?>
```

**output**

```
test
```

So again, from what I can read it's a scope issue.

Regards,

Eric

Comment: Hey I know how to deal with variables and functions. But unfortunately the post is not dealing with this issue. The var is reachable 1 level deep, but not 2 levels. And havent found out why...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question:

If I use

```
include_once("include/template_body.php");
include_once("include/header.php");
```

it does not work... if I use

```
include_once __DIR__ ."include/template_body.php";
include_once __DIR__ ."include/header.php";
```

it does make the variables accessible.

But I have no explanation for that behaviour, so it would be great if somebody could explain this to me :)

(Both versions make the content appear)

Comment: `include_once __DIR__ ."/include/template_body.php";` note:  leading '/' in the literal path as `__DIR__` does not have a trailing slash. Please always use absolute paths. You can use relative directories in absolute paths.